# Remove the PDB file/functionality from Lib

Tags: dll, pdb-files

I'm stuck in the following situation, I have been asked to rebuild a website, the original site was built and the solution had 5 projects, 4 of these where the different data layers and one of them was the actual website.

I only have the dll's of the 4 projects, so far I've managed to rebuild the website and adding the dll's to my project gives me access to the Entities and Repository layer etc... everything builds fine.

The problem is that when I run the project the debugger is trying to look for the Source files of the dll's that I've added which I don't have. Is there a way to remove the PDB file/functionality from the dll's that I've added? I don't need to or want to debug those dll's as I know that they are working correctly... and I dont have the code to change them if they arent.

Or to ask it in another way, is there a way to add them to my project and force them to not run with the Debugger?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to solve this problem I had to decompile the lib's of the four projects, create and place the code files in the exact directory that is specified in the PDB files and then compile and run the website.

I dont think it cared that the source files didn't compile again, it just needed to know that they where there.

After running the site i could delete the created path and source files and I haven't had a problem since.